# Casting from Double to Integer in DLX Processor

Tags: assembly, computer-science, dlx

I have some problem understanding how the casting from double to integer happens in DLX. hopefully an assembly geek can help me out!

Having the data below:

```
    .data   0   
    .global     a   
a:  .double     3.14159265358979    
    .global     x   
x:  .double     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16  
    .double     17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27    
    .global     xtop    
xtop:   .double     28
```

The assembly DLX code follows:

```
    ld  f2,a    
    add     r1,r0,xtop  
            ; how does r1 get the value of 224 instead of 28???!!!
loop:   ld  f0,0(r1)    
            ; load stall occurs here
    multd   f4,f0,f2    
            ; 4 FP stalls
    sd  0(r1),f4    
    sub     r1,r1,#8    
    bnez    r1,loop     
    nop         ; branch delay slot
    trap    #0  ; terminate simulation
```

I know that `double` is 64 bit divided in 8 bytes. A `r` or general purpose register can only have integer/fixed points number of 32 bit in group of 4 bytes.

In binary, 28 is `11100` and 224 is `11100000`.

I suspect since both of them have `11100` in common, so I guess when trying to fit a double into a `R` register, it takes the `11100000` and put it somehow in the 32bit register as `11100`...

really confusing stuff....any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r1` is loaded with the address of `xtop`. It's just an accident that it starts with `11100`. There is no "double to integer cast" in that code. It's 224 because you have 28 doubles defined before `xtop`, each taking 8 bytes (the pi followed by the numbers 1-27).

Comment: Thanks. So what will the value in `xtop` then? I thought value assignment happens in the data file so I assumed xtop has the value of 28.

Comment: Originally `xtop` is `28`. The code iterates through all the numbers backwards from `28` down to `1` and multiplies each one by `pi` (which is the value loaded into `f2`).